# React Native - refs crashing Android with The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, reactjs, view, reference, native

I have an issue with RN rc 0.30 where I am adding a refs view like this..( I removed the styles and other stuff just to clean it)

```
renderArray.push((
    <View ref={(node) => this.refsViewArray.push(node)}>
        <Animated.Image ref={(node) => this.refsImageArray.push(node) } />
    </View>
));
```

The above method of storing refs works fine on IOS but crashes Android with the The specified child already has a parent error.

Any body come across this?
Cheers

Comment: Please add stacktrace, as there is more than one type of "child already has a parent" error.